# Какой permission нужен для Service?

Tags: java, android, service

Хочу имплементоровать сервис в приложении.

Добавил в манифесте его

```
<service
        android:name=".tools.services.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
    </service>
```

Выделяет слово `service` и говорит, что если не добавлю permission то работать не будет

> Exported services (services which either set exported=true or contain an intent-filter and do not specify exported=false) should define a permission that an entity must have in order to launch the service or bind to it. Without this, any application can use this service.

Если нажимаю <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> и добавляю то, что просит то получается так

```
<service
        android:name=".tools.services.MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="">
    </service>
```

Но что нужно дописать в сам `android:permission=""`?

Comment: ну так если не собираетесь расшаривать свой сервис, то поставьте `android:exported="false"`

Comment: @ermak0ff а расшариватель это чтоб сторонние приложение могли использовать мой сервис? Или для чего?

Comment: да, в данном контексте я это и имел ввиду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ваш кастомный permission и вы сами должны придумать ему название, если хотите запрашивать его у того приложения, которое попытается вызвать ваш сервис. Например:

```
android:permission="com.yourpackagename.service.ACCESS"
```

Это разрешение будет запрашиваться при установке того приложения.

Ну и понятное дело permission не нужен, если не хотите, чтобы сервисом пользовались другие приложения. Тогда просто укажите `android:exported="false"`.